# What is alphabetical ordering for sort utility?

Tags: bash, sorting, posix, locale, collation

I call myself as POSIX shell wizard. But today I have shat into my pants.

So here is nothing strange:

```
bash# printf 'v10\nv1.' | sort
v1.
v10
```

because `.` has code `0x2e` and `0` has code `0x30`. But how about this:

```
bash# printf 'v101\nv1.1' | sort
v101
v1.1
```

WTF? Ok, I am wizard:

```
$ locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_DK.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So:

```
bash# printf 'v101\nv1.1' | LC_ALL=C sort
v1.1
v101
```

How can locales / collation make `"v101" < "v1.1"`?

I think that `en_US.UTF-8` locale have collation rule to strip `.` sign. This test shown that I have point:

```
bash# printf 'v102\nv1.01' | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort
v1.01
v102

bash# printf 'v102\nv1.03' | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort
v102
v1.03
```

Am I right? And if I am right who didn't like dots? UTF-8 or English-speakers or Americans?

Is that POSIX compatible behavior?

Comment: Yes, it's valid to ignore some chars when comparing. Slightly related WTF moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225675/weird-character-range-behaviour-with-locales-in-sed-regex-on-cygwin

Comment: Please tell me your memoirs will be titled, "OK, I am Wizard," with one chapter titled, "Today I have sh*t into my pants."  +1

Comment: https://www.madboa.com/geek/utf8/

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/95579/unix-sort-treats-dash-characters-as-invisible

Answer (score 2):

Yes it appears that dot is ignored when LOCALE is not C.  Also dash is ignored the same way.  And sort obeys the locale.  Learning something new everyday.

```
matt@xen:~/dev/OTOY2$ printf "aa\nab\nac\n" | LC_COLLATE=C sort
aa
ab
ac
matth@xen:~/dev/OTOY2$ printf "aa\n.ab\nac\n" | LC_COLLATE=C sort
.ab
aa
ac

matt@xen:~/dev/OTOY2$ printf "aa\nab\nac\n" | sort
aa
ab
ac
matth@xen:~/dev/OTOY2$ printf "aa\n.ab\nac\n" | sort
aa
.ab
ac
```

You may be interested to know that sort can do natural or numeric sorting too.
So 100 10 and 20 can be correctly sorted using -g or -h on the sort.

Under Linux there is also a --debug flag.

```
matthewh@xen:~/dev/OTOY2$ printf 'v101\nv1.1' | sort --debug
sort: using ‘en_NZ.UTF-8’ sorting rules
v101
____
v1.1
____
```

I think the whole answer is embedded in this massive spec:
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/